# PHP form fields filled email

Tags: php, html, forms

unfortunately I can not fix this form, if the fields are empty, it should not send the email

```
    <?php 
        $to = "info@alpafin.it"; 
        $subject = "Richiesta WEB da WEBFIN"; 
        $body = "Contenuto del modulo:\n\n"; 
        $body .= "Nome: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["1"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Cognome: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["5"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Telefono: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["2"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Email: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["6"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Provincia: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["3"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Professione: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["7"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Importo: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST["4"])) . "\n"; 
        $body .= "Note: " . trim(stripslashes($_POST['8'])) . "\n"; 


        if (!$body || !$cognome || !$Telefono || !$Email !$Provincia || 
        !$Professione || !$Importo || !$Note) {
        echo 'Tutti i campi del modulo sono obbligatori!';    
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['1']` ... `$_POST['8']` Please give your input fields descriptive names. Where is `$cognome`, `$Telefono` and the rest defined?

Comment: Where are you defining all those variables? I can only see that you're defining `$to`, `$subject` and `$body`. Are your input names actually called `1` etc?

Comment: `!$body` can never be the case at this point, because you are _filling_ $body with plenty of content in the lines above.

Comment: Should it be `...!$Email || !$Provincia..` (missing `||`)?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you not have variables $cogname, $telefono, $email ... .

Yo should declared that variables

```
$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST["1"]));
$cognome = trim(stripslashes($_POST["5"]));
$Telefono = trim(stripslashes($_POST["2"]));
$Email = trim(stripslashes($_POST["6"]));
$Provincia = trim(stripslashes($_POST["3"]));
$Professione = trim(stripslashes($_POST["7"]));
$Importo = trim(stripslashes($_POST["4"]));
$Note = trim(stripslashes($_POST["8"]));
```

this is code for declaration.

And then you can write.

```
if (!$name || !$cognome || !$Telefono || !$Email || !$Provincia ||  !$Professione || !$Importo || !$Note) {
    echo 'Tutti i campi del modulo sono obbligatori!';    
}
```